# How to make a sticky header?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a sticky navbar so that when I scroll down I want my logo, my search bar, sign in button and my navbar scroll down as well.

The problem is that when I'm scrolling down, my logo and nav bar go behind my slideshow; they do not show and they're also transparent. I'm working on it for 2 days now but couldn't figure it out.

```css
div#shopify-section-header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="shopify-section-header" class="shopify-section header-section">

  <header class="site-header" role="banner" data-section-id="header" data-section-type="header-section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="grid--full">
        <div class="grid-item large--one-half">
          <h1 class="header-logo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <a href="/" itemprop="url">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/_tagline_bpng?v=1512661427" srcset="//tagline_black_whitebkg_250x.png?v=1512661427 1x, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2045/6673/files/Ctagline_black_whitebkg_250x@2x.png?v=1512661427 2x"
                alt="test" itemprop="logo">
            </a>
          </h1>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <a class="contact-header-logo" href="/pages/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-item large--one-half text-center large--text-right">
          <div class="site-header--text-links medium-down--hide">
            <div id="ly-languages-switcher">
              <a href="#" id="ly40221" class="ly-languages-switcher-link current_lang">English</a>
              <span>/</span>
              <a href="#" id="ly40222" class="ly-languages-switcher-link">Français</a>
            </div>

            <div class="currencyRobo medium-down--hide">
              <div class="currencyRoboSelect">
                <select class="currencyRoboSelectBox" name="currencyRoboSelect">
                  <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
                  <option value="CHF">CHF</option>
                  <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
                  <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
                  <option value="USD">USD</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <span class="site-header--meta-links medium-down--hide">
              <a href="/account/login" id="customer_login_link">Sign in</a>
              <span class="site-header--spacer">or</span>
            <a href="/account/register" id="customer_register_link">Create an Account</a>
            </span>

          </div>

          <br class="medium-down--hide">

          <form action="/pages/search-results" method="get" class="search-bar" role="search">
            <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">
            <input type="search" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search all products..." aria-label="Search all products..." class="stop-mega-menu-reinit" autocomplete="OfF" id="_ispbxii_0" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
            <button type="submit" class="search-bar--submit icon-fallback-text">
              <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>
            </button>
          </form>

          <a href="/cart" class="header-cart-btn">
            <span class="icon icon-cart"></span> Cart <span class="cart-count cart-badge--desktop hidden-count">0</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav class="nav-bar sticky-header" role="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form action="/pages/search-results" method="get" class="search-bar" role="search">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" value="product">
        <input type="search" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search all products..." aria-label="Search all products..." class="stop-mega-menu-reinit" autocomplete="OfF" id="_ispbxii_1" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">
        <button type="submit" class="search-bar--submit icon-fallback-text">
          <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="fallback-text">Search</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: can you show me it from jsfiddle. your code snippet does not work

Comment: did you try z-index?

Comment: @JonDeWitt i used postion fixed

Comment: yeah, I believe z-index still applies though.

Comment: @JonDeWitt thank you man it works but i got another problem .my header goes under my nav bar i want to stay the same

Comment: can you recreate your issue on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Hi @marie you can look at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/navbar-static/

Comment: @JonDeWitt z-index works perfect  but the only problem is it hide half my slideshows if you can help me with that you are making my day

Comment: Hi @marie, I'm testing a answer right now.

Comment: @Marian07 Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this Fiddle. There are a couple of issues in your HTML, like your wrapping DIV is not closed. First try to fix the HTML, then add CSS to position your sticky DIVs separately.

HTML:

```
<div id="shopify-section-header" class="shopify-section header-section">

  <header class="site-header" role="banner" data-section-id="header" data-section-type="header-section">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1 class="header-logo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <a href="/" itemprop="url">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/_tagline_black_whitebkg_250x.png?v=1512661427" srcset="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2045/6673/files/Camomile_logo_tagline_black_whitebkg_250x.png?v=1512661427 1x, //cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2045/6673/files/Camomile_logo_tagline_black_whitebkg_250x@2x.png?v=1512661427 2x"
                alt="Camomile Beauty Always Cruelty free, Organic, Vegan and Safe skincare" itemprop="logo">
            </a>
          </h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <nav class="nav-bar sticky-header" role="navigation">
    <div class="wrapper">
      This is also sticky
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. At ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Nullam eget felis eget nunc. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt.

Massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper. Nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus. Nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla. Viverra nibh cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed blandit libero. Tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet. Sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat mauris. Libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Viverra adipiscing at in tellus. Lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat. Aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. Pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas. Id semper risus in hendrerit gravida. Tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit. Non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis.

Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit. Et malesuada fames ac turpis. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus. Leo vel orci porta non. Aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet purus gravida. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin ac. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. In metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum. Non tellus orci ac auctor augue mauris. Scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel. Faucibus et molestie ac feugiat. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis.

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#shopify-section-header .site-header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
  z-index:999;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100px;
}
div#shopify-section-header .site-header img{
  height:50px;
}
div#shopify-section-header .sticky-header{
  position:fixed;
  z-index:999;
  top:150px;
}
.content{
  margin-top:200px
}
```

Play around in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sztkujb2/10/

Answer (score 0):

The `code snippet` doesn't contain all the resources and it's hard to understand the environment in which the `navbar` is used. This is a important detail and its very useful for developers.

Today, I don't have anymore time to continue. I plan to update my answer or maybe other developers will continue from where I left.

---

**My approach** for a solution is:

*Notes*:

a) A sticky nav is already used, on large screens it display but only for the the menu elements. I think the request is to make the entire nav bar sticky.
b) A solution is necessary for only for large screens(desktops), making the entire nav sticky

1) **Clone** current HTML nav structure and append it after/before the original nav. Without this, after the original nav is sticky(`position: fixed`), the content will go upwards.
2) **After scroll** certain distance, add a `CSS class` to the orignal `nav` with sticky rules. (#style #UX) I would decrease size of certain elements in order to leave more visible space.
3) **Show**(`visibility : hidden`) the cloned nav structure.

Current code:

```
.sticky-header-structure-on #shopify-section-header{
    position : absolute;
}

.sticky-header-structure-on #shopify-section-header {
    position : fixed;
    width    : 100%;
    z-index  : 1;
    top      : 0;
}

/* Reset previous class for sticy menu element */
.sticky-header-structure-on #shopify-section-header .nav-bar.sticky-header,
.sticky-header-structure-on #shopify-section-header-clone .nav-bar.sticky-header{
  position : static;
  width    : auto;
}

#shopify-section-header-clone {
    display    : block!important;
    visibility : hidden;
}



var $body                             = $("body"),
    $sectionHeader        = $("#shopify-section-header"),
    $sectionHeaderClone   = $sectionHeader.clone(),
    $navBar                           = $sectionHeader.find(".nav-bar");

$sectionHeaderClone.css("display", "none");
$sectionHeaderClone.attr("id", "shopify-section-header-clone");
$sectionHeaderClone.insertAfter( $sectionHeader );

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  debugger;

  // Only for medium and large screens - when the large meniu is active
  // As in the CSS @media
  if( window.innerWidth <= 768 ) {
     return;
  }


  if( $navBar.hasClass("sticky-header")  ) {
    $body.addClass("sticky-header-structure-on");
  } else {
    $body.removeClass("sticky-header-structure-on");
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

After seeing your live code, I have added this and tested it:

```
div#shopify-section-header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: 999 is to make sure that no other z-index element gets ahead in Z index. 1 is ok, but if another div has 1 too, then you will get an overlap. It's safe to use 999

Comment: Hey @marie. Could you please share your code in an empty fiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Great. I have edited my answer. I have tested my solution on your site and it works 100%. Cheers @marie

Comment: @Bögözi Thank you dude but i still have the same problem it hides half of my sildshow

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth, your request is not very clear. Can you create an image (a screenshot) of what would you like to see exactly? how do you imagine the final result?

Comment: im sorry im not really good in explanation .like when im the top of the page after putting your code the nav bar  hides half of  my slideshow

Comment: Yes. That is the normal behavior. The sticky elements will always hide the rest of the elements underneath them. I would maybe try another approach, like creating a smaller header with a smaller logo and put them right in the main menu section. All in all, your header is way to large for what you are trying to achieve. I hope you will get it work. I am off now. Cheers.

Comment: @Bögözi I recommend using 3 z-index to a maximum. This will prevent you from adding huge z-indexes and losing your controll. I personally use variables for my z-index so I never lose controll

Comment: I appreciate your comment @DennisSpierenburg. As you probably know this is not an exact science. What works for one, does not necessarily work for the other. I always recommend trying out every possible solution you might find and if it's necessary to use 999 then you should do it! Cheers